# How to insert text at beginning of a multi-line selection in vi/Vim

Tags: vim, editing, viemu

In [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), how do I  insert characters at the beginning of each line in a selection?

For instance,  I want to comment out a block of code by prepending `//` at the beginning of each line assuming my language's comment system doesn't allow block commenting like `/* */`.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 920, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter 'command mode'
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual block mode
3. Move <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to select the columns of text in the lines you want to
   comment.
4. Then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and type the text you want to insert.
5. Then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, wait 1 second and the inserted text will appear on every line.

For further information and reading, check out "[Inserting text in multiple lines](https://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Inserting_text_in_multiple_lines)" in the Vim Tips Wiki.

Comment: The only bummer with this is that it appears Ctrl+V is overridden in GVIM.

Comment: Not for me (on linux) it's not

Comment: You can use Ctrl-Q as a replacement in gVim (as :help Ctrl-V explains) but you need to use hjkl to navigate in this mode rather than the arrow keys

Comment: To be able to use the arrow keys in visual mode on windows just add "set keymodel-=stopsel" to your _vimrc. More at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_arrow_keys_work_in_visual_mode_under_Windows

Comment: If your ctrl-v is overridden in windows gvim, you should edit the global vimrc to stop including mswin.vim.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to press escape twice though (on mac terminal)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+V works for me in GVIM, but I might have set that by hand...don't actually remember.

Comment: If anyone else got confused like me... That's Shift + i, not a lowercase l.

Comment: Don't forget to install the REAL Vim on Ubuntu since the default Vi editor is vim-tiny and it does not work the same.  $ sudo apt-get install vim

Comment: Shift+i takes me back into insert mode and I lose the block selection that I get through CTRL+V. Any reasons?

Comment: The "wait one second" part was what was confusing me on previous attempts to discover this method.

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't do anything after pushing esc? I waited like 10 seconds for something to happen on less than a hundred lines -- Never mind, I was pushing `Shift + v` not `CTRL + v`. @vkaul11 Probably the same thing what you did lol

Comment: :help visual-operators -> I = block insert , A = block append

Comment: Sorry if not related, but anyone knows how to paste something at the beginning of lines in a block.  Basically same steps as mentioned in the answer, but instead of typing at step 3, pasting an already yanked text (let's say too complex to type in full again)?

Comment: CTRL not shift! That's what I had confused so watch out! Now then could you please tell me how to uncomment a selection of lines?

Comment: Does anyone know why it takes exactly one second between escaping Visual mode and inserting the characters on subsequent lines? I'm just curious.

Comment: @mgouin Hopefully you figured this out over the past year, but I'll leave this here in case anyone sees your question - you can always use `Ctrl-R (register)` to put (paste) while in insert mode. So, something like `Ctrl-V` `Shift-I` `Ctrl-R` `"` `Esc`.

Comment: @brhfl Thanks you for taking the time to put the trick to my old question... It's funny, I found about the Ctrl-R in search mode (/) but I did not realize I could use it in that case also.  Thanks!

Comment: @alienCY yes, it must be visual block selection so do it with `Ctrl-v`. To uncomment, select in the same way and then hit `x` to delete them.

Comment: The confusing bit for me was that in Step 2 you have to press Ctrl + "Uppercase V", so in effect Ctrl + Shift + v to enter Visual block mode.

Comment: @ankur_kachru : for me ctrl+v (lower case) works just fine. tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41).

Comment: Took me a while to figure out that you really have to press `Esc`, and not the command mode-key (which is `Ctrl-C` for me), when exiting VISUAL BLOCK.

Comment: Works in Emacs Evil mode. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in vim 7.4.629. Shift + i doesn't take me to --INSERT-- mode

Comment: @Alecz it's not supposed to show you that mode, but you will be able to insert just like it says.

Comment: this works for me on debian 11.

Comment: The "wait 1 second" step is useless, the modification is done as soon as the final Esc is typed. At least on neovim, would the behavior different with vim?

Comment: OMG!!! This is magic :)

Answer (score 221):

This replaces the beginning of *each line* with "//":

```
:%s!^!//!
```

This replaces the beginning of *each selected line* (use visual mode to select) with "//":

```
:'<,'>s!^!//!
```

**Note** that `gv` (in normal mode) restores the last visual selection, this comes in handy from time to time.

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense.  And removing the text goes as follows: '<,'>s!^//!!

Comment: What is the meaning of the exclamation marks in the above answer? (:%s!^!//!)

Comment: @HKK, normally one uses the forward slash character / as a delimeter for the search and replace command.  In this case we are inserting a forward slash as part of the search and replace so we use an alternative delimeter, namely the exclamation character !

Comment: +1 This works in VsVim where (Ctrl+V) (Shiift+I) Esc doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! Also, to replace the END of each line you might write: %s!$!//!

Comment: +1, had no idea you could use something else as the regex delimiter (here I was using `/` and having to escape the `//` in `:s/^/\/\/` instead of writing `:s!^!//`)

Comment: This actually works. Commonly here, the 2nd highest vote tally is actually the correct answer...

Answer (score 103):

The general pattern for search and replace is:

```
:s/search/replace/
```

*Replaces the first occurrence of 'search' with 'replace' for current line*

```
:s/search/replace/g
```

*Replaces all occurrences of 'search' with 'replace' for the current line, 'g' is short for 'global'*

This command will replace each occurrence of 'search' with 'replace' for the current line only.  The % is used to search over the whole file.  To confirm each replacement interactively, append a 'c' for confirm:

```
:%s/search/replace/c
```

*Interactive confirm replacing 'search' with 'replace' for the entire file*

Instead of the % character you can use a line number range **(note that the '^' character is a special search character for the start of line)**:

```
:14,20s/^/#/
```

*Inserts a '#' character at the start of lines 14-20*

If you want to use another comment character (like //), then change your command delimiter:

```
:14,20s!^!//!
```

*Inserts a '//' character sequence at the start of lines 14-20*

Or you can always escape the // characters like:

```
:14,20s/^/\/\//
```

*Inserts a '//' character sequence at the start of lines 14-20*

If you are not seeing line numbers in your editor, simply type the following:

```
:set nu
```

Comment: to remove the beginning #: instead of :14,20s/#/^/, you should use :14,20s/#//

Comment: @cn1h I think this will replace other `#` in the line as well. You should use `^#` instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the basics. It's good to know why something happens.

Answer (score 49):

Another way that might be easier for newcomers:

```
 some█
 code
 here
```

Place the cursor on the first line, e.g. by

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

and type the following to get into insert mode and add your text:

<kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>

```
 // █some
 code
 here
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get back to command mode and use the digraph:

<kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

```
 // some
 // code
 //█here
```

<kbd>j</kbd> is a motion command to go down one line and <kbd>.</kbd> repeats the last editing command you made.

Comment: Thats really simple :). If you are having trouble with it may be because you are typing a bar (the other symbol with your \ ) `|` instead of a capital `I`. I thought it was a `|` at first.

Comment: If I do "5." it deletes 5 character from same line. How do I make it delete 5 character at once from each line ?

Comment: @RahulPrasad Let's say you have 25 lines, then beginning at the front of the first line just record 5xj into a register and play that register 24 times, for example:  qa5xjq25@a    But it would be better if you posted this as an actual question if it doesnt exist already...

Answer (score 29):

And yet another way:

- Move to the beginning of a line
- enter Visual Block mode (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>)
- select the lines you want (moving up/down with <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>, or jumping to a line with [line]<kbd>G</kbd>)
- press <kbd>I</kbd> (that's capital i)
- type the comment character(s)
- press <kbd>ESC</kbd>

Comment: thanks, this help a lot with modifying file in servers without additional plugin of VI

Answer (score 27):

This adds `#` at the beginning of every line:

```
:%s/^/#/
```

And people will stop complaining about your lack of properly commenting scripts.

Comment: What if you want to add # on only selected (or few) lines

Answer (score 16):

If you want to get super fancy about it, put this in your .vimrc:

```
vmap \c :s!^!//!<CR>
vmap \u :s!^//!!<CR>
```

Then, whenever in visual mode, you can hit `\c` to **c**omment the block and `\u` to **u**ncomment it. Of course, you can change those shortcut keystrokes to whatever.

Comment: Upvoted because it introduced something new - `vmap`!

Answer (score 14):

Yet another way:

```
:'<,'>g/^/norm I//
```

`/^/` is just a dummy pattern to match every line.  `norm` lets you run the normal-mode commands that follow.  `I//` says to enter insert-mode while jumping the cursor to the beginning of the line, then insert the following text (two slashes).

`:g` is often handy for doing something complex on multiple lines, where you may want to jump between multiple modes, delete or add lines, move the cursor around, run a bunch of macros, etc.  And you can tell it to operate only on lines that match a pattern.

Comment: actually the :g command isn't necessary. This will do: :'<,'>norm I//

Comment: And :s is better to use in this case, too.

Comment: This is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

To insert "ABC" at the begining of each line:

1. Go to command mode
2. `% norm I ABC`

Comment: This adds the text to the left of the first non-space character in the line.

Answer (score 3):

For commenting blocks of code, I like the [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin.

Select some text:

```
Shift-V
...select the lines of text you want to comment....
```

Comment:

```
,cc
```

Uncomment:

```
,cu
```

Or just toggle the comment state of a line or block:

```
,c<space>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) plugin.

eg. put this to your vimrc:

```
let maplocalleader=','
vmap <silent> <LocalLeader>c <Plug>VisualTraditional
nmap <silent> <LocalLeader>c <Plug>Traditional
let g:EnhCommentifyBindInInsert = 'No'
let g:EnhCommentifyMultiPartBlocks = 'Yes'
let g:EnhCommentifyPretty = 'Yes'
let g:EnhCommentifyRespectIndent = 'Yes'
let g:EnhCommentifyUseBlockIndent = 'Yes'
```

you can then comment/uncomment the (selected) lines with ',c'

Comment: You can also use Nerd Commenter at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218

Answer (score 1):

Mark the area to be comment as a visual block (`<C-V`)

and do `c#<ESC>p`

1. `c`hange it to "#"
2. put it back

If you do it often, define a short cut (example `\q`) in your .vimrc

```
:vmap \q c#<ESC>p
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone's multi-line-selection is actually a paragraph, there is no need to manually select the lines. vim can do that for you:

1. `vip`: select and mark the whole paragraph
2. `shift-i`: insert text at line beginning
3. `escape`: leave insert mode/enter normal mode [line beginnings still selected]
4. `escape`: unselect line beginnings

Answer (score 0):

Mapping of most voted answer:

1st visual select the desired lines, then execute `<leader>zzz`, which values:

```
vnoremap <leader>zzz <C-V>^I-<Space><Esc>
```

- `<C-V>` to enter visual mode
- `^` goes to start of line ( or use '`0`' to 1st non blank)
- `I` to insert in block mode
- `-<Space>` to insert '- ' (for example, edit as you need)
- `<Esc>` to apply same insert to all visual block lines

Or of last visual selection from normal mode:

```
nnoremap <leader>zzz gv<C-V>^I-<Space><Esc>
```