# copying just specific lines in a file with vim

Tags: vim

Could someone please tell me know how to copy specific lines, for example
Lines 10-20, 22, 24-30 in a file, so I can paste it to another file?
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253380/how-do-i-insert-text-at-beginning-of-a-multi-line-selection-in-vi-vim/3875539#3875539) stackoverflow post as someone had pointed out, however, I'm asking a different questionwhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fun little idea. Paste this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
command! -nargs=* Y :call YankList(<f-args>)
fun! YankList(...)
   let yanklist = []
   for i in a:000
      if match(i, "-") != -1
         let split = split(i, "-")
         let yanklist = yanklist + range(split[0], split[1])
      else
         let yanklist = yanklist + i
      endif
   endfor
   call setreg('"', "")
   for i in yanklist
      call setreg('"', getline(i), "al")
   endfor
endfun
```

Now you can specify lines to yank to the unnamed register. So do:

```
:Y 10-20 22 24-30
```

and use `p` to paste them wherever you want them. (inclusive)

I'd like to edit this post even though it's old to suggest the more "vimmy" way of doing this. See `:help usr_10 | 131`.

You could do:

```
10GV20G"ay
22G"AY
24GV30G"Ay
G"ap
```

Also, if there were some specific pattern that each of these lines contained, then you could grab them by said pattern. Say for example I wanted to yank all lines containing the word "foo", then I could do

```
:g/foo/y "
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution using Registers.

Using your scenario you provided, needing to yank Lines 10-20, 22, 24-30

Just yank each group with "A".

> :10,20y A
>
> :22y A
>
> :24,30y A

At this point you have each of those sets of lines copied to your "A" register. Now you you can use `p` to paste as you normally would OR you can use `"Ap` (double quote, Letter of Register, then `p` to paste just those you yanked with to the A Register.

Read more about Registers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers) and [Here](http://usevim.com/2012/04/13/registers/)

Answer (score 2):

Use visual mode, or directly:

```
:10,20yank
```

Copy to a new file:

```
:new | put | 0d
```

Usually, you'll either have a criterion, e.g. move all lines containing `pattern` to the end:

```
:g/pattern/m$
```

To copy (:copy or :t)

```
:g/pattern/t$
```

To yank to a register:

```
:let @a="" | g/pattern/y A
```

Now, you can use it wherever you like e.g. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to paste it.

If you don't have patterns like that to use, just use text motions, e.g. <kbd>}</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`y A` to append a block of lines till the next empty line to register `a` etc.

---

**Edit** PS. I thought I'd explain a bit more ***why*** I mention `m$` to move to the end (a personal favourite of mine):

If you opt to move/copy lines to the end of the file (`m$`), you can then write them to another file at once. E.g.

```
 :$mark a
 :g/pattern/t$
 :'a,$w newfile.txt
```

Copies the lines matching to file `newfile.txt`. Now delete the copy from the source file:

```
 :'a,$d
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the both files open - invoke directly from the command line as `vim fileone filetwo` or open vim and then `:e file`. You can then switch between them with buffer commands, for two files `:bn` and `:bp` are equivalent (buffer next, previous). Then just copy the lines.

This can be done pretty easily: `10G` to go to line 10, `y10y` to copy the next ten lines, then `:bn` and `p` to stick it in the other file.