# Changing text rectangulary in Vim

Tags: vim, insert, block

In [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) it is possible to insert text in multiple lines at once with the `I` command, like in [an answer Stack Overflow question *How do I insert text at beginning of a multi-line selection in vi/Vim?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253380/how-do-i-insert-text-at-beginning-of-a-multi-line-selection-in-vi-vim/253391#253391). However, this only works for real inserting. If I want to remove some characters at the same time this doesn't work.

For example, I want to change

```
000 one
000 two
000 three
000 four
```

to

```
111 one
111 two
111 three
000 four
```

I would do this by calling `^V3ggllx` to remove the 000 from the first three lines and then `^V3ggI111^[` to insert the 111 at the same positions, which seems quite awkward to me.
(The above means, going to visual blockwise mode, marking all the zeros in the first three lines and removing them. Then go to visual blockwise mode again, marking the start of the first three lines, going to insert mode for multiple lines, inserting the 111 and exiting with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.)

There must be a better way to do this. The most annoying thing is that I have to select the region again after removing the zeros. If the region was still selected after the removal it would be fine. Also if would be possible in multiple insert mode to remove characters, it would be fine too. But if I try this, only the first line is changed.

Comment: Thanks to you all. The best answer for this specific question was of course melpomenes, but the other answers provided other very useful hints, too.

Answer (score 5):

Re-selection is the simple and quick `gv`; you can then use `I111^[` to insert the new text. But, as @melpomene's answer shows, this isn't actually necessary.

<sup>(But I thought I'd mention it so you can apply this new knowledge in other situations.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, since you're replacing with the same character, you can use `r` after selecting:

```
^V2jer1
```

This has the benefit of avoiding insert mode altogether.

By the way, `3G` accomplishes the same thing as `3gg`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your column of `0`s selected, replacing them with `1`s is as easy as hitting `r1`:

```
<C-v>2jer111
```

(But Nikita already posted this… aaah multi-tasking…)

Depending on the complexity of your real usecase, a substitution might be a viable alternative:

```
V2j:s/^000/111<CR>
```

Since we are at it, using `:normal` and `<C-a>` could help you with this specific situation:

```
V2j:norm 111<C-a>
```

Comment: Interesting approach with `^A`, but note that if `nrformats` includes `octal` (which it does by default), Vim interprets `000` as octal, and `111^A` on `000` results in `0157`. `73^A` would give `0111`, but still with a leading zero.

Comment: I always forget that *my* settings are not *everybody*'s settings. ;-)