# Completely cancel a rebase

Tags: git

I performed a rebase like this:

```
git rebase --onto master new_background_processing export_background_processing
```

That didn't do what I wanted it to, so I performed a reset:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

I got my branch back to the state it was, but I received this message when I type git status:

```
# You are currently rebasing branch 'export_background_processing' on 'e378641'.
```

How do I cancel that rebase completely? Not sure what that means per se.

Comment: git rebase --abort

Comment: Git 2.12 now provides `git rebase --quit`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309)

Answer (score 792, accepted):

Use `git rebase --abort`. From the [official Linux kernel documentation for `git rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html):

```
git rebase --continue | --skip | --abort | --edit-todo | --quit
```

Comment: In my case the `git rebase --abort` did not work, because I messed something. I only got following error: `error: could not read '.git/rebase-apply/head-name': directory of file does not exist`. The `git rebase --quit` [described bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/2296044) solved my problem.

Answer (score 153):

In the case of a past rebase that you did not properly aborted, you now (Git 2.12, Q1 2017) have  `git rebase --quit`

See [commit 9512177](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9512177b68263085fef84cdbd45ecdee7bfe2377) (12 Nov 2016) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds). 
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 06cd5a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06cd5a1e01328724b7709ac232e36263e59f5f26), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### `rebase`: add `--quit` to cleanup rebase, leave everything else untouched
>
> There are occasions when you decide to abort an in-progress rebase and
>   move on to do something else but you **forget to do "`git rebase --abort`"
>   first**. **Or the rebase has been in progress for so long you forgot about
>   it.** By the time you realize that (e.g. by starting another rebase)
>   it's already too late to retrace your steps. The solution is normally
>
> ```
> rm -r .git/<some rebase dir>
> ```
>
> and continue with your life.
>   But there could be two different directories for `<some rebase dir>` (and it obviously requires some knowledge of how rebase works), and the "`.git`" part could be much longer if you are not at top-dir, or in a linked worktree. And "`rm -r`" is very dangerous to do in `.git`, a mistake in there could destroy object database or other important data.
>
> Provide "`git rebase --quit`" for this use case, mimicking a precedent
>   that is "`git cherry-pick --quit`".

---

Before Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), The stash entry created by "`git merge --autostash`" to keep the initial dirty state were discarded by mistake upon "`git rebase --quit`", which has been corrected.

See [commit 9b2df3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b2df3e8d093145f1628af82b94f6dcfc85b9646) (28 Apr 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3afdeef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3afdeef33e1d7912b8b135df2ea3fef3a3cf60bc), 29 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b2df3e8d093145f1628af82b94f6dcfc85b9646): save autostash entry into `stash reflog` on `--quit`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>
>
> In [a03b55530a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a03b55530ab844974b7058042a015fcfcd9e7a53) ("`merge`: teach --autostash option", 2020-04-07, Git v2.27.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf10200871d9e7e1fc9f54aca9b2fe40bc4e4ac7) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26)), the `--autostash` option was introduced for `git merge`.

(See "[Can “`git pull`” automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)")

> Notably, when `git merge --quit` is run with an autostash entry present, it is saved into the stash reflog.
>
> This is contrasted with the current behaviour of `git rebase --quit` where the autostash entry is simply just dropped out of existence.
>
> Adopt the behaviour of `git merge --quit` in `git rebase --quit` and save the autostash entry into the stash reflog instead of just deleting it.

Comment: This is very useful for avoiding the side-effect of resetting the working directory when changes are made on top of a `git rebase`, instead of losing them like I just did :P.

Answer (score 15):

You are lucky that you didn't complete the rebase, so you can still do `git rebase --abort`. If you had completed the rebase (it *rewrites history*), things would have been much more complex. Consider tagging the tips of branches before doing potentially damaging operations (particularly history rewriting), that way you can rewind if something blows up.

Answer (score 14):

If you are **"Rebasing"**, **"Already started rebase"** which you want to **cancel**, just comment `(#)` all commits listed in rebase editor.

As a result you will get a command line message

```
Nothing to do
```

Comment: For me, I already executed `:q`, after which `git rebase --abort` solved my issue

Comment: Combining this answer with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/253391/5285732 "adding a char at the at of a line in Vim" is amazing. Thank you!