# git still in status rebasing after reset to ORIG_HEAD

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

I got myself into trouble with an interactive rebase: Since I could not abort the interactive rebase via

```
git rebase -i --abort
```

I tried to

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

However, when I run git status, I now get

```
On branch feature1
You are currently rebasing. 
 (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is there a way I can reset git to the status before the interactive rebase?

Comment: What if you `continue` the `rebase` and then set your branch again to track remote which will remove the changes of `rebase`?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by setting to track remote? git rebase --continue gives me: `Already applied: 0000 fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`

Answer (score 1):

Before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c042c455d4ffb9b5ed0c280301b5661f3efad572/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L505)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> did not store `ORIG_HEAD` correctly.

See [commit 8843302](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8843302307bb7d652f5adde759cd6a3c1a7fb1ea), [commit a2bb10d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2bb10d06db8a90920f1f518705a0bb9d39aa1db), [commit f3e27a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3e27a02d598084a0ef5c8dd6b410bd6a5c5299f), [commit e100bea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e100bea48102dca7e21359993085e89c7f154f9d) (04 Nov 2020) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c042c45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c042c455d4ffb9b5ed0c280301b5661f3efad572), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e100bea48102dca7e21359993085e89c7f154f9d): stop overwriting `ORIG_HEAD` buffer
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Caspar Duregger</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> After rebasing, `ORIG_HEAD` is supposed to point to the old HEAD of the rebased branch.
> The code used `find_unique_abbrev()` to obtain the object name of the old HEAD and wrote to both .git/rebase-merge/orig-head (used by `rebase --abort` to go back to the previous state) and to `ORIG_HEAD`.
> The buffer `find_unique_abbrev()` gives back is volatile, unfortunately, and was overwritten after the former file is written but before `ORIG_FILE` is written, leaving an incorrect object name in it.
>
> Avoid relying on the volatile buffer of `find_unique_abbrev()`, and instead supply our own buffer to keep the object name.
>
> I think that all of the users of `head_hash` should actually be using `opts->orig_head` instead as passing a string rather than a struct `object_id` around is a hang over from the scripted implementation.
> This patch just fixes the immediate bug and adds a regression test based on [Caspar's reproduction example](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAFzd1+7PDg2PZgKw7U0kdepdYuoML9wSN4kofmB_-8NHrbbrHg@mail.gmail.com). The users will be converted to use struct `object_id` and `head_hash` removed in the next few commits.

---

Note: from the [Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CA+JQ7M-ynq1cLN-3ZodXae=x-H5k7Ab6uPBwUFhG+kgtOvCgtA@mail.gmail.com/T/#u):

```sh
git-rebase -i
# edit XYZ
git-reset HEAD~
git-commit -C ORIG_HEAD -a
git-rebase --continue
git-show ORIG_HEAD
```

`ORIG_HEAD` does *not* point at the previous HEAD of the rebased branch.
ORIG_HEAD points to `XYZ`

"`git reset`" will update ORIG_HEAD to the current HEAD before resetting
so here `ORIG_HEAD` gets updated to point to `XYZ`.

One can use the **[reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)** to get the previous HEAD of the rebased branch after rebasing.
Immediately after the rebase, `branch-name@{1}` will point
to the pre-rebase HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

I am normally using Git Portable in a Windows command line. Running `git rebase --abort` or `git reset --hard` on the last commit had no effect there. `git status` still revealed that I am in status `rebasing`.

However, switching to the bash-shell of Git Portable, `git reset --hard` on the last commit brought me back to a non-rebasing status of `git status`.

Comment: It sounds like your "helpful" environment made `git rebase --abort` not work. In any case `git reset --abort` is the normal way to do this (no `git reset` required afterward).

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue and I found a top on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61770738/2608351) that fixed it for me.

```
git rebase --quit
```