# Git branch showing rebase?

Tags: git, github

I am learning git right now. I tried to rebase a file a while ago, but cancelled it. Ever since then, I have this showing up in turquoise in my git.

```
(updatingThesePages|REBASE-i)
```

but the current branch I am on is 'other' and not 'updatingThesePages'. How can I get out of this?

Thanks!

Comment: `git rebase --abort` to cancel the rebase. You can't rebase a file, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rebase in progress. Cannot commit. How to proceed or stop (abort)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902967/rebase-in-progress-cannot-commit-how-to-proceed-or-stop-abort)

Answer (score 0):

For cancelling a rebase done "a while ago", a more complete command would be [(with Git 2.12+) `git rebase --quit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309).

That will get rid of any lingering `.git/<some rebase dir>` in your repo.