# When git rebasing, git displays that I'm currently more commits through the rebase than there are commits to rebase

Tags: git

Apologies for the confusing question, I'm not sure how to describe it generally. I typed `git rebase master` to place my 4 commits in my current branch at the end of master's history.

But instead I am stuck in a state that says:

```
user@CPUNAME MINGW64 /d/Code/ClientRepo (branchName|REBASE 5/4)
```

5/4? How can I be 5 commits into the rebase if there are only 4 commits TO rebase?

`git rebase --continue` gives me the output: `fatal: cannot resume: .git/rebase-apply/final-commit does not exist.`

`git rebase --abort` seems to work, but after the command completes I still see `branchName|REBASE 5/4` indicating the rebasing never aborted.

Totally stuck. Advice politely requested.

Edit: I have since unblocked myself by re-cloning the repo into a different directory. This meant that I lost my commits. Thankfully, there weren't too many changes and I re-created them.

However, I still have the old directory stuck in this state and am very curious what the fix might be as I've never seen this situation before. I'm leaving the question open and will try out suggestions - perhaps a potential answer could help someone else in the future.

Now, the main questions are, what could possibly lead to this state and how to unravel it?

Comment: What was the state of your branch, and of master, before attempting the rebase?

Comment: My branch was created by branching off from master about ~20 commits back from where master is now.

In the meantime I added 4 commits to my branch.

Comment: What was the output of rebase prior to first showing this prompt?  It must have said something when it stopped processing ...

Comment: I would copy-paste it here but I've tried many things since then and the output is no longer in my history. But it seemed like normal rebase output ("applying commit1, commit2, etc...").

I do have the git status output from immediately after this prompt first showed:

`$ git status
On branch branchName
You are currently rebasing.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.11.1.windows.1

Comment: I'd try running `git fsck` on the broken repo just to see what it says, though I don't know how useful I'd expect it to be. I'd also try updating to latest git 2.13.0, just in case there's some fix that's applicable to your situation. Definitely sounds like a corrupted repo though, if you feel like being a good citizen, keep the broken repo and [file a bug report](https://git-scm.org/community).

Comment: I believe you have tripped over a Windows-Git bug, where the last commit in a rebase sequence can't be properly `--continue`d.  There was another question recently with the same bug, and I think VonC had a link to a bug report and/or fix. (The shell-prompt status comes about because you're still rebasing, and the number of steps left to go is "-1", so 4 minus -1 is 5.)

Comment: Oh interesting, that would certainly explain it. I'd be interested in seeing that question/answer.

Comment: Also @Adrian, running `git fsck` just gave me a long list of dangling commits/blobs. So you were right not much there. Seems that it really is just a git bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first think to check is if the issue persists with:

- a fresh clone
- the [latest Git for Windows (2.13)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

You will have the [new syntax `git rebase --quit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309): that will help properly abort a rebase in progress.
I don't find yet a bug report I might have mentioned before, I will check the [Git mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=git&w=2&r=5&s=rebase%20step&q=b).