# Git rebase causing merge conflicts on essentially all files - even untouched ones

Tags: git, rebase

The typical behavior of `git rebase` is a relatively "clean" merge from the base to the local.

Occasionally however things go south. Basically *every* file that has been touched in the base requires manual merging into the local - regardless of whether the files had even been touched/changed locally

Why would this happen? Is there a reasonable workaround?

**Update**

For some reason in *this* scenario

```
git pull
```

worked ***just fine***.  It required manual merging of ***one file*** - and that was a *valid* manual merge.

So I guess this question has in a sense devolved into "what are the conditions that a `git pull` were required as opposed to `git rebase`.  I will look for applicable Q&A.

Comment: As VonC notes in his (edited) answer, pull runs `git merge` rather than `git rebase`. If there are N commits to rebase, a rebase has the same amount of "pain" involved as running N separate merges, while a merge runs just *one* merge. So merge is, in a way, fundamentally simpler. Rebase is often better, but not always better. You can tell `git pull` to run `git rebase`, but I suggest avoiding `git pull` entirely: use `git fetch`, then *choose* merge vs rebase, based on what you have vs what you just got by fetching.

Comment: @torek  In this case the `merge` is clearly what I wanted: when actually is `rebase` working better? Feel free to add another answer.

Comment: Rebase isn't *better*, nor is it *worse*. It's just *different*. See, e.g., the related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45345564/1256452 (rebasing multiple branches) and the lower part of my answer, which is more about "why choose merge or rebase".

Comment: @torek: To clarify: I did not say "merge is better *always*": I said *in this case*.  Will look at your other answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason is the eol (end of line) characters, which might be different between the two branches.

Quit first tour current rebase (since [Git 2.12: `git rebase --quit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309))

Try again your rebase with the option (merge strategy) `-X ignore-space-at-eol`, to see if the issue persists.

---

> git pull works just fine

That is the difference between pull (fetch + merge) and rebase (replay commits)

```
 x--x--x--x--X     (master)
        \
         --o--o--O (origin/master)
```

A pull will merge two HEAD commits `X` and `O` who might differ only in one file.

```
 x--x--x--x--X-----M     (master after git pull)
        \         /
         --o--o--O (origin/master)
```

A rebase (or git pull --rebase) would replay master on top of origin/master, and previous '`x`' commits might introduce a lot of conflict, even if `X` (HEAD) only differ from one file from origin/master HEAD `O`.

```
 x--x--x
        \         
         --o--o--O--x'--X' (master)
           (origin/master)
```

Comment: I updated the OP:  `git pull` worked great in this case - so I need to do some homework to understand the differences in their workflow.

Comment: @javadba yes: a merge between two branch HEAD commits, versus replaying all commits from one branch onto the other.

Comment: can you add that to the body of your answer and maybe a bit more context?

Comment: I will, I am comutting (train) at the moment

Comment: Vous reveiller si tot.

Comment: why `git rebase --quit` and not `git rebase --abort`?

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb To force a rebase cleanup, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309).