# Correctly merging a feature into master

Tags: git, svn, merge

**Problem:**

I'm always running into the same problem when it comes to having several dependent feature branches.

```
master ---A---B---C
           \
feature1    D---E---F
                     \
feature2              G---H
```

I have something like this. Assuming both of these branches have been reviewed, I will merge `feature1` to `master`. Then checkout and pull `master`, then checkout and rebase `feature2` to `master`. Doing this, I always end up seeing the same conflicts over and over, especially with several branches.

**Good rebasing:**

I've seen online that in the above example, first I should do something like this to make sure I'm rebasing correctly:

*Rebase `feature1` to `master`*

```
master ---A---B---C
           \       \
feature1    \       D'--E'--F'
             \       
feature2      D---E---F---G---H
```

*Rebase `feature2` onto the new `feature1` commits*

```
master ---A---B---C
                   \
feature1            D'--E'--F'
                             \
feature2                      G'--H'
```

I would do this using `git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@{1} feature2`.

**Confusion:**

As I understand it, it's better to rebase like this because when you rebase, your branch will actually contain entirely new commits (i.e. `F` and `F'` above), which can cause unnecessary conflicts.

With all this in mind, what would be the correct approach to:

- Merge `feature1` into `master`
- Merge `feature2` into master`

I want to try and learn a recommended approach where I can be confident I won't receive painful conflicts every time with several dependent branches.

Comment: Your `Rebase feature2` diagram has a problem and would not result from the diagram appearing above it.  There are no hard and fast rules, but rebasing `feature2` on `master` (after merging `feature1` into `master`) should not necessarily cause merge conflicts.  Remember, most of feature2's functionality is already in master and there are just a few new commits being reapplied from a functional point of view.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was jusing https://coderwall.com/p/xzsr9g/rebasing-dependent-branches-with-git as an example/reference. Normally I would just merge `feature1`, then go and pull `master` and rebase `feature2` to `master`. I don't know what exactly is wrong with this, but I always end up with repeated conflicts down the line for things which shouldn't be conflicting.

Comment: You could try going with a pure rebase approach.  Rebase `feature1` on `master` and then fast forward `master`.  Then rebase `feature2` on `master` and again fast forward `master`.  This approach would mean that each functional commit from the feature branches would only be applied once to `master`.  But again, I'm still not convinced that your current workflow should necessarily be causing many conflicts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean by fast forwarding `master`? To give some context, I was doing something as above in a case where I had 5+ dependent branches, and there was a conflict I resolved in `feature`. As I was merging/rebasing each branch to `master`, I would repeatedly see the same conflicts from this branch over and over again.

Comment: Do you see that if you merge `feature1` into `master`, and then rebase `feature2` on `master` that you will be applying commits D E F which have effectively already been applied to `master`?  My suggestion is to avoid this by rebasing and fast forwarding `master` at each step.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you just mean to make sure you go back and pull `master` each time?

Comment: Sure @TimBiegeleisen Actually the best approach I've seen so far is to do exactly as we discussed, but to use `--onto` in case the commit hashes have changed during the rebase, so when you rebase `feature2` to `master` you can be sure you won't have any unnecessary conflicts.

Comment: See here: http://www.calebwoods.com/2014/07/02/rebasing-dependent-feature-branches/ what do you think of this approach?

Comment: `since the history for feature1 was rewritten we'll get merge conflicts` ... in general I don't see why this would always be true.  If the advice in that article works for you, then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this answer is two parts.  The first is about the mechanics of rebase, and the second is rebase vs merge.

#### The mechanics of a complex rebase

> I would do this using `git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@{1} feature2`

Yes: this works by splitting the argument to rebase: instead of just `feature1`, it's now `--onto feature1 feature1@{1}`.

Normally, we run `git rebase name`, e.g., `git rebase feature1`.  We have to first `git checkout feature2`.  Adding `feature2` to the end of the command (as quoted above) just does this `git checkout` step for us.  So in the case I'm calling "normal" here, there is only one argument to `git rebase`, typically another branch name like `feature1`.

But what `git rebase` does is to *copy* some commits, and to do this, it needs to know *two* things:

- *what to copy* (a list of commits), and
- *where to put* the new copies.

That one argument, `feature1`, does the heavy lifting for *both* of these.  That's great **when it works**, but for rebasing `feature2` onto the already-rebased `feature1`, it doesn't always work.

The reason it doesn't work (when it doesn't work) has to do with the graphs you drew.  You drew them in a kind of odd way, with branch names on the left.  This kind of drawing is misleading: it implies that each commit is on *one* branch, which just is not true.

Here's the first drawing again:

```
master ---A---B---C
           \
feature1    D---E---F
                     \
feature2              G---H
```

Q: Which branch is commit `A` on?  (Trick question!)

A: It's on *all* the branches.

These diagrams should be drawn with the commits on the left and the *labels* on the *right*, with the labels pointing to *one specific commit*—because that's how these things actually work in Git.  Here's the same diagram, redrawn:

```
--A--B--C   <-- master
   \
    D--E--F   <-- feature1
           \
            G--H  <-- feature2
```

By starting from the right and following the (internal and always backward-pointing) parent links from commit to commit, we can see that `C`, `B`, and `A` are on master; `F`, `E`, `D`, and `A` are on `feature1`; and `H`, `G`, `F`, `E`, `D`, and`A` are on `feature2`, for instance.

Now we can draw the *second* diagram, after the first `git rebase`, like this:

```
          D'-E'-F'   <-- feature1
         /
--A--B--C   <-- master
   \
    D--E--F   [reflog: feature1@{1}]
           \
            G--H  <-- feature2
```

This is where the split-up argument to `git rebase` comes in.

Normally, Git finds the set of commits that `git rebase` will copy by using:

```
git rev-list <argument>..<current-branch>
```

which here would be `feature1..feature2`.  This means *all commits reachable from `feature2`, except for all commits reachable from `feature1`*.  Now, *before* we moved `feature1`, that was the right set of commits: it was `H` and `G`.  But we moved `feature1` and now it is the *wrong* set of commits as it includes `F` back through `D` too.

Once we say `feature1@{1}..feature2`, though, we get the *right* set of commits again.  But now we've lost the place to copy, and this is why we need `--onto`: that's *where to put the copies*.

When the second rebase finishes, we should draw the final result like this:

```
                  G'-H'   <-- feature2
                 /
          D'-E'-F'   <-- feature1
         /
--A--B--C   <-- master
   \
    D--E--F   [reflog: feature1@{1}]
           \
            G--H  [reflog: feature2@{1}]
```

and since the reflogs are normally invisible, we can drop the bottom half of the diagram entirely.

#### Rebase vs merge

> As I understand it, it's better to rebase like this because ...

*Better* is a very slippery term.

There are two issues with rebase:

- It *copies* commits, then abandons the originals in favor of the new copies.  Does anyone else have the originals?  If so, you've made things difficult for them too: they, too, must abandon the originals in favor of the new copies.
- It *copies* commits.  The new copies are at least somewhat different from the originals (otherwise they would actually *be* the originals).  What, precisely, is different in the copies?  Is it important?  Did you break something in the process, i.e., introduce bugs?

Using `git merge` avoids these problems.  It inserts, instead, its own problems:

- The history is now tangled.  If it's necessary to figure out what happened, whoever is exploring the history may have to look down both "legs" of the merge.  Some argue that this is a positive, rather than a negative, because this is the *real* history, rather than a later, cleaned-up, artificial history.

  (I tend to favor the cleaned-up history but there is merit to both sides of this argument.)
- The merge itself could introduce bugs.

If you have a really good set of tests, that helps with both of the "introduce bugs" problems.

If it helps enough, it leaves only *one* rebase problem (assuming you're smart enough, or have a nice tool, to do your own complex rebases like this case): does someone else have the originals?  Balance your answer to that question against your answer to whether the tangled history is bad, in order to decide on merge vs rebase.

If you *don't* have good tests, well... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response and explanations. My take from this would be that using `--onto` will solve the case where you have unnecessary conflicts due to the commits being "different". I'd also say that if you're collaborating with others then you should always make sure you're rebasing to a clean copy of the branch from `origin`, since after the rebase, the commits will be different.

Comment: Remember, the others may have built their own commits atop the commits you're copying-and-abandoning. If so, they must copy *their* commits without re- or re-re-copying *your* commits, so they have their own `--onto` that they must manage somehow.

Comment: True, I suppose with 2 people it wouldn't be as much of an issue as it's easier to make sure that you both have the latest copy of `feature1`, but I can see how this would be an issue with numerous people collaborating. Do you have any thoughts on how to make this easier? I mean, you could end up with a case where `feature1` now has several branches merged into it, which means your colleague can no longer rebase to `feature1@{1}` as there are more commits on that branch now.

Comment: Git has some built in stuff to help, using `--fork-point`, but when it gets this complicated, it's often best to avoid rebasing. Instead of rebasing an existing branch, you can just make a series of branches: "version 0 of feature X", "version 1 of feature X", "version 2...", and so on.