# how to recover from stopped pull with rebase

Tags: git, filesystems, rebase, pull

I've stopped pull with rebase working on a big project after Intellij Idea warning.

After that, most of the files in the project comes brown and not in the tracked state, but what i have in my filesystem is ok, and i continue working on the project.

i even did some commits after that.

i would add all the files to be tracked, but some of them shouldn't be tracked.

i'm not shure about what to do, so i didn't try anything for now.

i want to find a solution to make it back to adequate state.

how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the status in a command line using the command git.

See, as described here, if a `git rebase --abort` (or, [with Git 2.12+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309), `git rebase --quit`) can remove the rebase in progress state.

Finally, try (if you are working on `master`)

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

That will replay your local commits on top of an updated master branch, which is what `pull --rebase` was supposed to do in the first place.