# How to force abort or kill a Git rebase

Tags: git

A stash got me into a merge with conflicts which got me in a rebase that I cannot abort or continue. Both give me message

> error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/onto': No such file or
>   directory

Is there a way to force a abort, reset? Or should I just start over with a fresh checkout.

I am using Git 2.21.0.

Answer (score 10):

If git status does report a rebase, the  [`git rebase --quit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309) would be the way yo cancel everything.

If not, you can try a `git reset --hard` (assuming you don't have any work in progress), and see if a `git status` will report a clean working tree.