# git rebase repeatedly asking me to run `git rebase --continue`

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am on my feature branch `my-feature`, I run rebase develop branch:

```
(my-feature)$ git rebase develop
```

Terminal shows a bunch of conflicts, and it is in `detached` mode now:

```
(detached*)$
```

I resolved those conflicts in detached mode and committed them.  Then, I run `git rebase --continue`, but now git again prompt me the following:

```
(detached*)$ git rebase --continue
Applying: my-feature my commit message
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

So, I again run `git rebase --continue`, but the same message shows to me, it is endless as long as I run `git rebase --continue`. Why? So, what am I supposed to do after I resolved conflicts to rebase to develop branch?

Comment: `git rebase --abort` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely cancel a rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289345/completely-cancel-a-rebase)

Comment: I updated my question now. I am asking a different thing than how to undo rebase now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When resolving a conflict on a rebase, you **should not commit** them, let the rebase handle the commit part*.

<sub>*Unless you are in an interactive rebase, where you can stop for amending commits.</sub>

Once you have edited the conflictual files you must add them (not commit) and then you can `git rebase --continue`. Here is an example:

```sh
git rebase develop
# conflict
vi file-with-conflict
git add file-with-conflict
git rebase --continue
```

This will continue rebasing to the next step (next commit), and if there is a new conflict, you will have to resolve it the same way. And so on until there is neither conflict to solve nor commits to rebase.

---

In your case, you may need to first `git rebase --abort` to get a clean slate, and then try again to rebase.

Comment: I added and commited. I mentioned it in my question. I am doing exactly the steps you mentioned except I didn't use `--amend --no-edit` in my commit command.

Comment: Then my guess is there is one file that has not been edited properly, could you show the result of `git status` (or better `git status -sb`)?

Comment: Oh I just saw your edit. The `--amend` part is really important, since it tells git not to add a new commit but to fix a rebase. Another solution is **not to commit**. I've editer my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

You already accepted an answer, but let me add this, with my own emphasis:

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
>   **If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
>
>   already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.**

Sometimes, while rebasing—which means copying a series of commits—you will find that one of the commits that Git thought was still required, was in fact not required.

Consider, for instance, this situation:

```
...--o--*--R--S--T   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

(The uppercase letters stand in for commit hash IDs.  Newer commits are towards the right.  You made commits `A`, `B`, and `C` earlier.)  You've decided you would like to `git rebase` your `feature` onto your `master`.  If it all went as you'd expect, you would end up with this:

```
                   A'-B'-C'  <-- feature (HEAD)
                  /
...--o--*--R--S--T   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

where `A'` is *like* `A`—it makes the same *changes*, but to commit `T` instead of to commit `*`—and `B'` is like `B` and `C'` is like `C`.

So, `git rebase` schedules the copying of `A`, then `B`, then `C`.  It detaches HEAD (hence "is in detached mode") at `T` and executes the first copy.  If all goes well, you now have:

```
                   A'  <-- HEAD
                  /
...--o--*--R--S--T   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

Git then proceeds to attempt to copy `B`.  This copy step *fails* due to conflicts, leaving you in the state you saw.

You now begin resolving conflicts.  Inspecting the first conflict, you see that what what you did in `B` is already taken care of by commit `S`, so you choose their code from `T`, which resulted from their change in `S`, rather than your code from `B`.  Inspecting the second conflict, you see that what you did in `B` is already taken care of by commit `R`, so you take their code from `T` again.  This repeats until you have resolved all conflicts, taking *no* changes from your own `B`.

If you now run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

your Git will say:

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

No, you didn't *forget*, you just resolved all conflicts by, in the end, *dropping* your commit `B`.  So the bold-text advice above applies and you can just run:

```
git rebase --skip
```

to tell Git: *Yes, drop my commit entirely, and proceed to attempt to copy `C` now.*  Assuming *that* copy works, the rebase will finish and you will have:

```
                   A'-C'  <-- feature (HEAD)
                  /
...--o--*--R--S--T   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

which is not quite what you expected originally, but is what you needed after all.