# How to insert text at the beginning of a multi-line selection on GVim?

Tags: windows, vim

I have a large block of text, and I want to insert comment delimiters `//` at the beginning of every line. I am using X11 forwarding to run GVim from a remote Linux box on my local windows machine. I can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to enter the block selection mode as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253380/how-do-i-insert-text-at-beginning-of-a-multi-line-selection-in-vi-vim). When I try to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to insert in the selected block, it deletes what I have selected and instead inserts the letter "I" at the top line of my selection and puts me in insert mode.

Any suggestions on how I can insert comment delimiters at the beginning of every line in a block? I would love to solve the problem with block insert, but a work-around would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Vim is set to `behave mswin`. You can use `:behave xterm` to make it behave in the default manner, and then the other suggestions should work.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `:s` command?

- select those lines
- then      `:s#^#//#`

Comment: When I press ":" it just deletes the lines and inserts ":", even when I'm not in insert mode.

Comment: Do not use select mode, but use visual mode (for lines, one usually uses `V`)

Comment: @GBleaney it sounds like your Vim is set to `behave mswin`? Try `:behave xterm` and then follow @Kent's suggestion.

Comment: @Ben , it will let him insert `:behave ...` :)

Comment: @Ben, if you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Not only did that fix my problem, it fixes a lot of other little issues I've had as well.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of replacing the selection is a characteristic of *select mode*. You need to use *visual mode* for the column-insert via `I`.

How you got into select mode depends on your configuration. If `<C-Q>` gets you there, you likely have the `cmd` value in the `'selectmode'` setting.

> ```
>   This is a comma separated list of words, which specifies when to start
>   Select mode instead of Visual mode, when a selection is started.
>   Possible values:
>      mouse        when using the mouse
>      key          when using shifted special keys
>      cmd          when using "v", "V" or CTRL-V
> ```

Also check the options listed under `:help :behave`. You may have turned on `:behave mswin`, and that causes all such unexpected effects.