# How to add text at the beginning/end of visual selected block(multiple lines) in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to add some text at the beginning/end of selected block(multiple lines) in Vim.

I have the command for single line but not multiple lines:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.tex,*.html vmap  bb :s/\%V\S.*\S\%>v/\\[ \0 \\]/<CR>
```

It prefixes and suffixes \[ and \] to selected line.

But I'm looking for a way to multiple lines so that I can prefix/suffix with in multiple lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253380/how-do-i-insert-text-at-beginning-of-a-multi-line-selection-in-vi-vim

Answer (score 0):

Mark the area to be prefix/suffixed as a visual block of lines (V)

and do `:s/.*/\\[&\\]/`  (or use your short cut `bb`)

If you do it often, define a short cut (example \q) in your .vimrc

```
:vmap \q :s/.*/\\[&\\]/<CR>
```

Comment: @AronLee, if you have your `bb` command defined, (1) define a visual block of lines = `V` + down-arrows (2) `bb`  that should work